# Ubuntu 14.04 Freeze after some time of working

Tags: 14.04

I am Android developer and recently i remove ubuntu 13.10 and install new ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Every things working good when i use ubuntu 13.10. There is no hardware issue in my side.

Now i only install Java JDK, Virtual Box, Genymotion for android virtual device, and Eclipse SDK of Android.

When i start developing on eclipse, genymotion device, after some time ubuntu 14.04 LTS gone freeze,i cannot have any control to switch anythings.

I search on google and also in many communities, forums but they only give answer like what to do after Ubuntu freeze, some answer like [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes), (this is good but not proper things.)

they do not tell me how to avoid or remove freeze problem happened in ubuntu 14.04.

is there any solution to avoid this problem ?

My System Configuration is :

Intel Pentium 2.9 GHz Processor, 8 GB RAM, 500 HDD.

if there is any solution please tell me because this problem is generating 2 to 3 times in hour of work.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The Virtual Box in my experience can be very fussy with new releases of Kernels. I would remove that and see if the lockups persist. At least then you know what to fix if it is Virtual Box.

Comment: yah sure @MeerBorg, but also freeze when i use Firefox for only browsing

Comment: I had a similar issue, it was a faulty memory module. Use the memory checker utility that is in the boot menu.

Comment: @MeerBorg how to check this and is it affect in Ubuntu Boot Loader ?, means my ubuntu will not crashed after do this.

Comment: Can you `ssh` in when it is frozen? If you can, check the output of `dmesg` for any errors.

Comment: @bain when ubuntu freeze i have to restart my pc to work i cannot do any things before restart.

Comment: I too have the same problem.

Comment: I have same problem. But sometimes i could point mouse to logout button. Which saves a minute. But mouse stutters too.

Comment: @bain i ask this question because i already check [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) but its not helped me, there is no control working while ubuntu freeze, do you have answer of my question then said me otherwise don't make duplicate mark.

Comment: @RahulMandaliya If your computer is randomly crashing or freezing it is either faulty hardware or a bug that should be reported on Launchpad. It would help to diagnose the issue if you can run a serial console (see [KernelDebuggingTricks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks)) and capture the crash message. There is no way for us to help you with the information we have at the moment.

Comment: @RahulMandaliya The alternative would be to close it as a bug. The current consensus is that closing "crash/freeze" questions as duplicates of _"What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?"_ is more helpful for most users, but if you disagree you are welcome to discuss the issue at http://meta.askubuntu.com/